# How to see just the public methods in Resharper?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

When I press Cntrl+F12 I get the member view pop up which shows me all the members of a class I am in. I can then scroll up or down or filter the search to choose the member I am looking for.

Is it possible to have the same type of pop up but only show the public methods of my class?

Comment: Up vote this feature request if you want to see this in R# https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-460851

Answer (score 5):

I don't know a solution in ReSharper but the Class View (View->Class View) of Visual Studio can filter public members.

[image: Class View]

But the Class View has one disadvantage: You cannot synchronize the class view to current class in editor window. But if you always navigate to your classes by Class View you can use its filter.

P.S.: I don't use Class View because of the described disadvantage.

Comment: Thanks. Yes a major disadvantage without synchronization.

Answer (score 2):

You can restrict what is shown from the toolbar.

[image]

Comment: @Thanks Mark. I was hoping for a Resharper shortcut that does this. In the meantime, can you tell me where you got toolbar from?

Comment: It's just part of the object browser. I can't see a way to show/hide it.

Comment: @JD Currently, ReSharper doesn't provide filtering by visibility. Not sure there's a request for this kind of functionality, and you're welcome to submit one to [ReSharper issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/RSRP)

Comment: @gorohoroh : Thanks. I would have thought other users would want something like this as it helps focus on the interface of my classes.

Comment: Feature request added to Resharper issue tracker here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-460851

Answer (score 0):

So looking at other answers, I see that sometimes you'd want a little bit simpler and quicker solution which works well for not really huge files.

1. In your context menu choose `Outlining -> Collapse to definitions`, or `Ctrl+M, Ctrl+O`
2. Search for `public`

Search will highlight all public definitions of methods/variables/classes/etc, and since it's collapsed you can quickly skim over your definitions.